# search for files with pattern [A-Z] in unix

Tags: linux, shell

I want to search files matching with the pattern [A-Z].

I created some files like test.txt,MANUAL.txt,etc in a directory. Now, I want to filter the files according to the search pattern [A-Z]

Example: suppose I have a file which has following content :

```
A SCRAPER sITe is a WEBsite that features content123 stolen from other sites and presented as original.
```

I want my search results matching the pattern [A-Z].

EDIT: only "SCRAPER" should show up in the search results

Comment: What are the example filenames you want to be matched?

Comment: is this as simple as `ls -l | grep [A-Z]`, i think you might want to texplain what you expect that search pattern to do, i dont think it means what you think it means

Comment: Edit your question to indicate if you expect the literal string "[A-Z]" OR if you understand that a search pattern "[A-Z]" means one upper-case letter. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grep like this:

```
grep '[A-Z]' *
```

to search all lines matching any upper case letter.

**EDIT:** In order to search lines only with uppercase letters use:

```
egrep '^[A-Z]+$' file
```

OR to grep only uppercase words:

```
grep -Po '\b[A-Z]+\b' file
```

Comment: this does not work, lowercase letters are also getting filtered

Comment: You mean you want to search lines that only have capital letters?

Comment: @user3432300: use `grep -Po '[A-Z]+' *.txt`

Comment: @anubhava: This still filters words with lower case letters.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: Its almost working. It does not filter words with all lower case letters but gives matches like Abc. I want results to be only ABC

Comment: I found somewhere that it may not filter the exact results due to some "locale setting" which needs to be set to "C".

Comment: @user3432300: it shouldn't print `Abc`, it should print only `A`. Could you [provide an example input](http://ideone.com/2LxYhE)?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: yes ur right. M sorry I should have written A. it prints out only A.

Comment: @user3432300: if you want only *full words* then [`grep -Po '\b[A-Z]+\b'`](http://ideone.com/FpwBmJ) (similar to [@glenn-jackman's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22536729/4279))

Comment: @user3432300: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for uppercase *words* in a file:

```
grep -o '\<[[:upper:]]\+\>' file
```

If you're looking for which files in this directory contain an uppercase word:

```
grep -lo '\<[[:upper:]]\+\>' *
```